# "component instance "uut" is not bound" when simulating test bench with GHDL simulator

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl, ghdl

I am having a problem with using GHDL (http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to simulate my VHDL design. So, when I use the command `ghdl -e Averager_tb` to compile the test bench with GHDL I get the warning:

```
Averager_tb.VHD:33:3:warning: component instance "uut" is not bound
Averager_tb.VHD:11:14:warning: (in default configuration of averager_tb(behaviour))
```

To compile the test bench for simulation I use the following commands:

```
ghdl -a Averager_tb.VHD # the test bench file is Averager_tb.VHD
ghdl -e Averager_tb # the entity for the test bench is Averager_tb
```

And the output of my design stays unchanged throughout the testbench, I also find that the print statements inside the Design are not executed.

To execute the compiled test bench simulation I use the command:

```
ghdl -r Averager_tb
```

However when I simulate the same testbench on http://www.edaplayground.com using the Aldec Riviera Pro 2015.06 simulator I find that the print statements within the design are executed and the output changes as I would expect.

Why is this and how might I fix it?

Here is the entity declaration in my design

```
-- Entity Declaration in Design
entity Averager is
port (
clk : in std_logic;
ClockEnable : in std_logic;
Averager_In : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
Averager_Out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);
end Averager;
```

Below is the test bench:

```
-- TEST BENCH

architecture behaviour of Averager_tb is
  signal X : real := 0.0; -- a real math variable initialized to 0
  signal sine : real := 0.0; -- a real math variable initialized to 0

  component Averager
  port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    ClockEnable : in std_logic;
    Averager_In : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    Averager_Out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
  end component;

  signal clk : std_logic := '0';
  signal ADC_clk : std_logic := '0';
  signal Input : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal FPGAOutput : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal int_sine : integer;
  constant clk_period : time := 5 ns;

begin
    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
  UUT : Averager
  port map (
    clk => clk,
    ClockEnable => ADC_clk,
    Averager_In => Input,
    Averager_Out => FPGAOutput
  );

  ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out, it was a stupid mistake, I forgot to compile the design as well as the test bench. The solution was to compile and run like so:

```
ghdl -a Averager_Bettertb.VHD
ghdl -a Averager.VHD
ghdl -e Averager_tb
ghdl -r Averager_tb #--stop-time=10us
```

Comment: Having done that, if you read the docs or ghdl's internal help messages, you'll find an option that writes a Makefile to make rebuilding the design easier in future.

Comment: Thsnks, I've just been using a bash script to rebuild my code so I'll take a look, much appretiated.